# Sending Message via DatagramChannel

Tags: java, string

I am sending a message via a DatagramChannel as follows:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
buf.clear();
String request_message = "request";
buf.put(request_message.getBytes());
buf.flip();

int bytesSent = udpserver.send(buf, successor_port_1); // udpserver is a DatagramChannel
```

I then read the message on the server:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
buf.clear();

String message = new String(buf.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(message); //print message for testing purposes

if (message == "request"){
    //code here does not get executed
 }
```

The problem is, my code doesn't enter the "if" statement even though message = "request" which also seems to be confirmed by my print statement.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: String comparison has nothing to do with networking. String comparison is used everywhere. It should not be handeled as a TCP/IP specific feature. It is data marshaling feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `String`s in java need to be compared with `.equals`, so your test should be:

```
if (message.equals("request")){
```

This is because, in Java, `==` tests whether two object are the same *instance* (it tests reference equality - do both the references point to the same memory) rather than equal.

You can carry out a quick test:

```
System.out.println("request" == new String("request"));
```

Output:

```
false
```

For more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2071828) SO answer.